# Parallel version of `map()`

Tags: r, parallel-processing, tidyverse, purrr

I have a function that takes multiple arguments.

```
my_function <- function(list_of_vectors, list_of_scalars){
 ....
return(list)
}
```

I want to use `map()` over my function but using a parallel call that would use multicores. `my_function()` is very computationally expensive, and I need to call it to create output for over 1000 points. ( `list_of_vectors` is a list of 1000 vectors and `list_of_scalars` is a list of 1000 scalars)

Is there a `mcmap()` equivalent or any other formulation ? I had a look at other threads but none solved my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `future_map()` from the `furrr` package as a drop-in replacement.

This is a very flexible function; how it distributes your computation will depend on a previous call to `future::plan()` (`furrr` is built on top of the `future` package), e.g.

```r
future::plan(multicore, workers = 4)
future_map(...)
```

to run your job on 4 cores on the same machine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [map()](https://github.com/parallel-js/parallel.js#mapfn) function from [Parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel) library, like this:

```
const p = new Parallel([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
const log = function () { console.log(arguments); };

// One gotcha: anonymous functions cannot be serialzed
// If you want to do recursion, make sure the function
// is named appropriately
function fib(n) {
  return n < 2 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
};
    
p.map(fib).then(log)

// Logs the first 7 Fibonnaci numbers, woot!
```

Comment: The OP tagged the question with [r], meaning they are looking for solutions in R, not Python ...